# Divide any large number by its divisor then calculate the result to original value

Tags: discrete-mathematics

What I'm trying to do is to divide any large whole numbers then after the result a formula will convert it back to the original value:

**For example:**

```
736,778,906,400 / 10,000,000 = 73,677
```

700 Billion divided by 10 Million the result will be `73,677`

I must find a way to convert the 73,677 back into 736,778,906,400 (the starting/original value).

Is there any formula or algorithm to do this?

Comment: This is hard to follow.  Your quotient is actually $73677.89064$. You can recover the original numerator by multiplying by $10$ million. If you round the quotient then you can't recover the numerator...you've discarded information.  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: @lulu yes, but when I tried to multiply the qiotient by 10 million it produces this result: 736770000000, not the exact value (like the original value).

Comment: Right, because you discarded information when you rounded.  If you don't want to discard information, don't round.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to decide what the operation "$/$" means to you.

Now that you have decided what it means, do you agree with the equation on the next line?

$$ 736{,}770{,}000{,}000 / 10{,}000{,}000 = 73{,}677.$$

If you don't agree with that, you really need to explain what you think "$/$" means.

If you do agree with the equation, then consider this question:

> Someone had a number $x,$ they performed the operation $x / 10{,}000{,}000$
>   according to my interpretation of the operation "$/$",
>   and the result was $73{,}677.$
>   Supposing I have been told the information in the preceding sentence but have not been told what actual number they used for $x,$ is there any way for me to determine with certainty whether the original number $x$ was $736{,}778{,}906{,}400,$
>   or $736{,}770{,}000{,}000,$ or possibly something else?

The answer to this question is "no," just as you cannot tell by looking at a puddle of water whether the puddle came from an ice sculpture of a unicorn that melted, or
an ice sculpture of a pineapple that melted, or something else.

The answer to your original question is then also "no."

If you don't like the answer, try explaining what this all is for.
People usually don't just go around dividing large numbers by ten million;
it seems likely you have some larger task that this is part of.
If you do, perhaps someone can suggest a better way to do things.

Answer (score 0):

I just realised from the answer that when you divided:

$$ \dfrac{736,778,906,400}{ 10,000,000} = 73,677 $$

But you discarded the decimal part, so your answer is actually

$$ \dfrac{736,778,906,400}{ 10,000,000} = 73,677.8906400 $$

You can convert it to orginal by multiplying $10 \text{ million}$.